# how to handle the alias for year column - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have attempted to write a query that finds the user's work anniversary,

Table "*emp_detail*":

| emp_no | join_date | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2017-07-03 | 5 0 |
| 2 | 2017-07-25 | 4 11 |
| 3 | 2020-07-01 | 2 0 |
| 4 | 2020-07-13 | 2 0 |
| 5 | 2020-07-20 | 1 11 |
| 6 | 2020-08-20 | 1 1 |
| 7 | 2020-02-29 | 2 4 |

**Query:**

```
SELECT
emp_no, 
join_date,
join_date +
         INTERVAL (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURDATE()) -
                   EXTRACT(YEAR FROM join_date)) YEAR
         AS "anniversary_date_this_year",

CONCAT(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, join_date, CURDATE())," ",TIMESTAMPDIFF( MONTH, join_date, CURDATE() ) % 12) as FinalYear

FROM emp_detail
```

please also see the [example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pVdA39PcbTbmrHYrfTfKCj/5)

### **Query result:**

| emp_no | join_date | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2017-07-03 | 5 year 0 month |
| 2 | 2017-07-25 | 4 year 11 month's |
| 3 | 2020-07-01 | 2 year 0 month |
| 4 | 2020-07-13 | 2 year 0 month |
| 5 | 2020-07-20 | 1 year 11 month's |
| 6 | 2020-08-20 | 1 year 1 month |
| 7 | 2020-02-29 | 2 year 4 month's |

Need help with the "Year" or "Years" alias, 5 **Years** 0 **month**, 1 **Year** 1 **month**

Any help would be great!

Comment: Use common CASE operator: `.. CASE WHEN {expression for years amount} = 1 THEN 'year' ELSE 'years' END ..`.

Comment: Or use a common phrase for both: _1 year(s) 4 month(s)_. By the way, it should be "months", not "month's".